# x11vnc sddm systemd-service

Tags: sddm

My problem is, I cannot find the right solution for starting up x11vnc by systemd-service on kubuntu 18.04 with sddm display manager. With other Ubuntus and 'lightdm' or 'mdm' I had never problems.
Is there anybody who is able to describe the whole process.
I think the problem has to do with finding the right authorization (-auth).
My service looks the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start X11VNC
Requires=display-manager.service
After=display-manger.service

[Service]
Type=forking
User=ud
ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -auth /var/run/sddm/* -display :0 -forever -loop -noxdamage -repeat -rfbauth /home/ud/x11vnc.pass -rfbport 5900 -shared $

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I already made many alternative modification, but the log always says that -auth has failed.

Who can help?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that systemd is not bash and you're listing files with "*". Your exec command should look something like this:

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/x11vnc -auth /var/run/sddm/* -display :0 -forever -loop -noxdamage -repeat -rfbauth /home/ud/x11vnc.pass -rfbport 5900 -shared"
```